# How to join substrings to define integer variable?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to join two substrings into one that defines an integer variable.

Example:

```
Dim ACTGPA as Integer
Dim ACTGPB as Integer 
Dim ACPrio as Integer

ACTGPA = 5
ACTGPB = 10
```

Following a lot of code I have a loop that selects the value from a recordset containing a number column called either "TGP_A" or TGP_B".

```vb
Set rs4 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Syllabus WHERE Mis_Name = '" & strMisName & "'")
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In rs4.Fields
    If item.Name = "TGP_A" Or item.Name = "TGP_B" Then
        If Nz(rs4(item.Name).Value, "") > 0 Then
            If strACCon1 = "" Then
                strACCon1 = item.Name         
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next item
```

I want to set the ACPrio value to either the value of ACTGPA or ACTGPB, depending on which item name is chosen in the loop.

Using replace I remove the _ from the item name in order to define ACTGPA (or B).

I get

> "Error 13, type mismatch"

on this next line. Probably because it thinks I am trying to set ACPrio (integer) to something that is a string - but I am trying to write the integer ACTGPA (or ACTGPB).

```
ACPrio = "AC" & Replace(strACCon1, "_", "")
```

Should be the same as this:

```
ACPrio = ACTGPA 'eg. settings the ACPrio value to that of ACTGPA (or ACTGPB), which is 5 (or 10).
```

Comment: You can't assign a variable name calculated from a string. I would suggest to use a collection to store the values and so make them accessable by name at runtime. I will prepare an answer now for you with a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a string to reference a variable (or its value) by name.

But you can add the necessary values to a collection with their name and then access them later on by name, like in this sample:

```vb
Public Sub Sample()
    Dim ACTGPA As Integer
    Dim ACTGPB As Integer
    Dim ACPrio As Integer

    ACTGPA = 5
    ACTGPB = 10

    ' Prepare the collection by adding the values with their name:
    Dim col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection
    col.Add 5, "ACTGPA"
    col.Add 10, "ACTGPB"

    Dim strACCon1 As String

    ' Set for testing to "TGP_A":
    strACCon1 = "TGP_A"

    ACPrio = col("AC" & Replace(strACCon1, "_", ""))
    Debug.Print ACPrio

    ' Set for testing to "TGP_B":
    strACCon1 = "TGP_B"

    ACPrio = col("AC" & Replace(strACCon1, "_", ""))
    Debug.Print ACPrio
End Sub
```

The output is

```
5
10
```

And maybe you can omit the variables `ACTGPA` and `ACTGPB` at all now, if it fits to your concept and overall code.